# MultiLookup column and CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, caml

How to create CAML query to find items which have all specified lookup values?

The query below returns items which have item1 or item2, or (item1 and item2).
But I would like to return only items which have (item1 and item2)

```
<Where>
  <And>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Column1' />
        <Value Type='LookupMulti'>item1</Value>
     </Eq>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Column1' />
        <Value Type='LookupMulti'>item2</Value>
     </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Actually it is working as expected. There was an typo in CAML query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following caml got from CAML Designer:

```
 <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='lookuptest' />
            <Value Type='LookupMulti'>China</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='lookuptest' />
            <Value Type='LookupMulti'>USA</Value>
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

To avoid wrong type or spelling, I would highly recommend to use CAML Designer to build CAML Query：
[image]